# Unity Como vincular un sprite aleatorio con su sonido

Tags: imagen, unity, sonido

Lo que necesito es un ejemplo para que pueda unir las dos listas para que se reproduzcan juntos imagen y sonido. (todo sin modificar luego el resto de funciones y comportamientos para los sprites que parten del codigo adjunto).

Objetivo: se reproduzca el sonido correspondiente a una imagen aleatoria que aparece en un botonprefab.

Tenemos

- un prefab Buttons.
- Sprite, una lista de la cual se instancian de forma aleatoria los sprites en el prefab.
  -lista de sonidos

Problema: coordinar el sonido con la imagen.

Intente varias cosas. Lo mas cerca que estuve fue sonidos desde el index, pero a los sonidos los reproduce tal cual orden de la jerarquia, y los sprites los manda aleatorios asi que tampoco coinciden imagen con sonido.

```
 [SerializeField] private Sprite[] Imagen = new Sprite[];
public List<string> AgregarImagen = new List<string>();
 [SerializeField] private AudioClip[] Sonido = new AudioClip[];



  void AgregarlaImagen()
    {
        int cuenta = botones.Cuenta;
        int index = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < cuenta; i++)
        {
             AgregarImagen.Add(Imagen[index]);
index++
}
void Shuffle(List<Sprite> list)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
           Sprite temp = list[i];
            int random = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, list.Count);
            list[i] = list[random];
            list[random] = temp;
        }
    }
```

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Lo más fácil sería crear una pequeña clase que sirva para contener un sprite y un sonido, al iniciar creas un array de clases de este estilo, asignándoles el sprite y el sonido al azar si quieres, y luego tan solo sacas una clase del array, coges su sprite y reproduces su sonido y ya está, siempre tendrás el mismo sprite asociado al mismo sonido

Comment: La opción de @Benito-B es buena opción. Otras que podrias plantear son: nombrar los archivos de audio igual que los sprites, y asi al cargar el sprite X cargar el audio con el mismo nombre. Otra es que cuando mezcles los sprites, mezcles los audios de la misma manera usando la función que ya tienes.